# How to solve UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm using Android Studio 3 and I am trying to use OpenCL with my device.
The APK compiles and fails at:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcutils.so" not found

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def appDir = getProjectDir().toString()
def includeDir = appDir + "/src/main/cpp/include/"
def libDir = appDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/"
def arm64lib = libDir + "/arm64-v8a/"
def armeabilib = libDir + "/armeabi-v7a/"

android {

compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.miche.androidopencltest"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
            cppFlags "-I${includeDir}".toString()
            cppFlags '-std=c++11'
        }
    }

}

splits{
    abi{
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v7a"
        universalApk false
    }
}


project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1]


buildTypes {
    release {
        //minifyEnabled false
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I can't find the right .so even in the /lib/ folder of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find the right .so even in the /lib/ folder of the device.

According to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes:

> Apps should not use native libraries that are not included in the NDK because they may change or be removed between different versions of Android.

`libcutils.so` is one the private NDK libraries.

If the app targets API level 24 or higher, your app will crash because you are trying to access to the private libraries. Note that your app is targeting 28 by having `targetSdkVersion 28`.